# Should I use a single interface for Feign and Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, netflix-feign

The Spring integration with Feign supports using Spring MVC annotations for mapping a Feign interface:

```
@FeignClient("multiplier")
public interface MultiplierApi {
    @GetMapping("/multiply")
    public Long multiply(@RequestParam("one") long one, @RequestParam("two") long two);
}
```

I could place the `MultiplierApi` interface into an API package, and use it with `@EnableFeignClients` in client programs and as an implemented interface for my controller:

```
@RestController
public class MultiplierController implements MultiplierApi {
    public Long multiply(long one, long two) {
        return one * two;
    }
}
```

This seems to allow me to remove duplication that might otherwise occur between the controller and the client interface, reducing the likelihood that the mappings will get out of sync. Is there any disadvantage to sharing the API definition in this way?

Comment: roughly all [disadvantages of coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_(computer_programming)#Disadvantages)

Comment: @zapl The API is, by definition, *exactly* the coupling point between services. The Feign interface provides *exactly* the information *required* to interact with the backend service. Reusing that doesn't introduce any coupling that isn't implicit in the services' cooperation in the first place.

Comment: It's a service description for the client. You are not required to `implement` it to "implement" it. You could for example choose to have multiple controller classes to implement such an interface with multiple methods. Or you might want to add additional hidden parameters to your methods. Or use different types. All those things are no longer possible by actually `implement`ing it. Having said that, I would still do it because of all the advantages.

Comment: @zapl I'm aware that it's not *required* to implement it, and that there may be situations where I want to provide additional parameters such as `@AuthenticationPrincipal`. The multiple-controller issue is a good point to keep in mind, though.

Comment: Take a look at [Why is it such a bad idea to share an interface between server and client?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/322871) I can't find how to refute the Jimmy T and Leonardo Villela comments.